# How to get timezone with offset in php?

Tags: php, date, datetime

Hi i am from India my timezone is `Asia/Calcutta` and offset is `+5.30`

How to get dynamic timezone and offset?

Dynamic timezone means when an user access my website. This user can see his/her local time in my site.

If some one visit my website outside of India then how to display the local time?
I have tried to find the timezone and offset but unable to get any satisfy answer. So i post here my question. Pleas help me and share your answer with example.

Thanks

ChatFun

Answer (score 0):

You might use browser geolocation functionality:

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

... that will give you Lat and Lon which you might then use in a call to Google TimeZone API

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/outputFormat?parameters
```